# How to resize social media Icon?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Trying to make the social media icon bigger. Ive tried height, width, and font-size syntax but nothing changes.

```
<h3>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
</h3>
```

```css
.fa-instagram {
  color: #e4c95e;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

Comment: add e.g. class ```fa-xl```, see https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/style/size

Answer (score 3):

If you're using font awesome, add this in your class name

```
<h3>
 <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook fa-1x"></a>
 <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></a>
 <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram fa-3x"></a>
</h3>
```

Please see the official documentation for font awesome https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/style/size

Answer (score 1):

Font Awesome does have some [built-in classes for resizing icons](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/style/size) (relative sizing table from link):

> | Relative Sizing Class | Font Size | Equivalent in Pixels |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | fa-2xs | 0.625em | 10px |
> | fa-xs | 0.75em | 12px |
> | fa-sm | 0.875em | 14px |
> | fa-lg | 1.25em | 20px |
> | fa-xl | 1.5em | 24px |
> | fa-2xl | 2em | 32px |

However, you can also resize icons manually using the `font-size` CSS property. Let me explain.

When you use a Font Awesome icon class, it uses CSS to add an obscure Unicode character to the page. The font file provided by Font Awesome then tells the browser to render that character as the associated icon. This means that as far as the browser is concerned, these icons are just text.

Example:

```css
.font-50{
  font-size: 50px;
}

.font-100{
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<h3>Normal</h3>
<i class="fa fa-camera"></i>

<h3>50px</h3>
<i class="fa fa-camera font-50"></i>

<h3>100px</h3>
<i class="fa fa-camera font-100"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you don't have the font linked. Here's a quick example of what I think you are missing on your HTML page:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
```

Comment: U have that linked as well. Still wont resize.